# logstash parsing IPV6 address

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, morgan

**I am a newbie to logstash / grok patterns.**

In my logfile i have a line in this format as below:

```
::ffff:172.19.7.180 - - [10/Oct/2016:06:40:26 +0000] 1 "GET /authenticator/users HTTP/1.1" 200 7369
```

When I try to use a simple IP pattern matching  %{IP}, using grok constructor, it shows only partial match:

```
after match:    .19.7.180 - - [10/Oct/2016:06:33:58 +0000] 1 "POST /authenticator/searchUsers HTTP/1.1" 200 280
```

So, only a part of the ip address matched, as the portion 'after match' still shows remaining portion of ip address.

Queries:
1. What is this format of IP address ::ffff:172.19.7.180? 
2. How to resolve this issue, to ensure IP address is correctly parsed?

**BTW, I am using nodejs middleware morgan logger, which is printing IP address in this format.**

Comment: Have you tried the `%{IPV6}` grok pattern?

Comment: @Val `%{IP}` is `(?:%{IPV6}|%{IPV4})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the log contains **both** IPv4 and IPv6 addresses separated by a colon, so the correct pattern you need to use is the following one:

```
%{IPV6:ipv6}:%{IPV4:ipv4}
```

Then in your event you'll have two fields:

```
"ipv6" => "::ffff"
"ipv4" => "172.19.7.180"
```

This will work until [this issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/issues/161) is resolved.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work.  I get an error both in logstash and also in grok constructor web site.  Parse error for %{IPV6:ipv6}:%{IPV4:ipv4}

Comment: Can you update your question with your current configuration?

Answer (score 1):

These IP addresses are in the IPv4-Embedded IPv6 Format and the `%{IP}` doesn't match it. The only way to go is to either use `%{DATA}` or write your own regex.

Comment: You can match them by concatenating both as depicted in my solution. It's not 100% correct, but the parsing works and you have a valid IPv4 address.

Comment: @Val Sure you can, but I rather extract in one go than stitch fields back together later. Personal preference really.

Comment: Yes, indeed, at least the OP has two options to choose from ;-)